# UIScrollView-UIPageControl Animation

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Maybe you have any example of infinite animation that makes the uipagecontrol move his subviews?

Comment: provide more information

Comment: Please put more information

Comment: I found solution :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good example for Image Sliding Page by Page – UIScrollView Auto scrolling like Image Slider

here:

http://sugartin.info/2012/01/21/image-sliding-page-by-page-uiscrollview-auto-scrolling-like-image-slider/

good luck!